# How to get Ubuntu download for a Mac?

Tags: installation, mac, downloads

I am trying to download Ubuntu to put it on my daughter's MacBook (just installed new HDD, so no operating system on it)

But from my Windows PC all I can see is the Windows Ubuntu. Can I use that, or is there a specific place I can go to get the Ubuntu download for a Mac please?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recent MAC with an Intel CPU (anything since ~2006), you should just simply grab [the proper (32 or 64-bit) version](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and that's it.

In case you sport an older Mac computer (with PowerPC), you can grab the PowerPC images from the mirrors. Like from [Germany](http://swtsrv.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/linux/distributions/ubuntu-dvd-release/13.04/release/).
List of mirrors: [Scroll down here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

But I'm pretty sure you have an Intel machine. :)
Update: If you want, you [can use your pendrive](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to install Ubuntu.
It's a Windows-only tool, but you mentioned you are on Windows now.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that -- I assume you just insert the disk and power-up holding down the C key?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Mac, but you have to boot up the disc, yes. You can also use a pendrive if that works better for you (I always do this, so I don't have to burn/waste time and money.) See my edit.